# If I know the max size of many tmp slices, should I set capacity when creating them?

Tags: go

If I need to use tmp slices in a function and the function will be called many times, their max capacity will not exceed 10. But the length of them are varied. Just for example, maybe 80% of them only have size of 1. 10% of them have size 3 and 10% of them have size 10.

I can think of an example function like the following:

```
func getDataFromDb(s []string) []string {
    tmpSlice := make([]string, 0, 10)
    for _, v := range s {
        if check(v) {
            tmpSlice = append(tmpSlice, v)
        }
    }
    ......
    return searchDb(tmpSlice)
}
```

So should I do `var tmpSlice []string`, `tmpSlice := make([]string, 0, 0)`, `tmpSlice := make([]string, 0, 5)`, or `tmpSlice := make([]string, 0, 10)`? or any other suggestions?

Comment: If the searchDb argument does not escape, then the function as written is the best choice. The function will execute with no  heap allocations for the slice. If the argument does  escape, then the best choice will depend on the actual workload and the runtime's strategy for allocating extra capacity on append.  In this case you will need to measure to determine what's best.  If searchDb calls to a database, then performance difference between the choices will be in the noise.

Comment: @ThunderCat hi, thanks a lot for the reply. Sorry that I don't quite understand what `escape` means here. And yeah, searchDb will call a database from its name. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Fastest would be if code doesn't allocate on the heap.

Create variables that allocate on the stack and do no escape (pass variables by value, otherwise they will escape).

Escaping you can check by adding `-gcflags "-m -l"` on building.

Here is an example that shows if we substitute `slice` with array and pass it by value, it results in fast code without allocation (on the heap).

```
package main

import "testing"

func BenchmarkAllocation(b *testing.B) {
    b.Run("Slice", func(b2 *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b2.N; i++ {
            _ = getDataFromDbSlice([]string{"one", "two"})
        }
    })
    b.Run("Array", func(b2 *testing.B) {
        for i := 0; i < b2.N; i++ {
            _ = getDataFromDbArray([]string{"one", "two"})
        }
    })
}

type DbQuery [10]string
type DbQueryResult [10]string

func getDataFromDbArray(s []string) DbQueryResult {
    q := DbQuery{}
    return processQueryArray(q)
}

func processQueryArray(q DbQuery) DbQueryResult {
    return (DbQueryResult)(q)
}

func getDataFromDbSlice(s []string) []string {
    tmpArray := make([]string, 0, 10)
    return processQuerySlice(tmpArray)
}

func processQuerySlice(q []string) []string {
    return q
}
```

Running benchmark with `benchmem` gives this results:

```
BenchmarkAllocation/Slice-6             30000000            51.8 ns/op       160 B/op          1 allocs/op
BenchmarkAllocation/Array-6             100000000           15.7 ns/op         0 B/op          0 allocs/op
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. But sorry that I don't quite understand what you want to express. So what is your final suggestion on my question? Are you suggesting to use `var tmpSlice [10]string`? and then use tmpSlice[i] = assignment in the loop? and finally when accessing it,  loop again until the last non-empty string? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I suggest using slices without any premature optimization. After you identify that this method is really slow, you can apply what I have suggested. Imagine reader of the code seeing ```make([]string, 0, 10)```, why 10? why not 42? Not to create questions better to avoid such an approach if there is no reason. The problem with arrays is that is it very easy to write code that makes them as slow as slices. If it answers your question pls accept the answer, so I can update it with details from the comment.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that `searchDB` does not retain a reference to the slice passed to it. It seems unlikely that the function retains a reference given the variable and function names.

These options have the same memory and performance characteristics:

```
 var tmpSlice []string
 tmpSlice := []string{}
 tmpSlice := make([]string, 0)
 tmpSlice := make([]string, 0, 0)
```

None of them allocate memory until the first append operation. If these are your only options, then pick one of the first two because they are easier to read.

This option will have the best performance:

```
tmpSlice := make([]string, 0, 10)
```

This ensures that the backing array for the slice is allocated once. There will be no reallocations of the backing array as values are appended.

If `searchDB`'s argument does not escape, then the one allocation for the backing array will be made on the stack.  This is the best possible performance. You can find out if the argument escapes by building with the `-gcflags "-m -l"` option.

Given that `getDataFromDb` invokes a database operation, any performance difference between the options will be in the noise. It's more important is to write clear and simple code than to optimize this.

I would probably go with the `var tmpSlice []string` over `tmpSlice := make([]string, 0, 10)` because there's no need to understand where the value 10 came from with the former.

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
var tmpSlice []string
```

This would give you an empty string slice and you can append as needed.
Unless the slice range gets big and you know the dimension beforehand, otherwise I wouldn't pre-allocate memory for it

Comment: Thank you very much for this tip. so you suggest to set it to `nil` first. OK, cheers. ^_^

Comment: This does not answer the question.